# Deep linking URL question

Tags: flash, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting, deep-linking

I'm running an all-Flash website and I've got it deep linking. I'm now trying to make it SEO friendly by breaking up the sections into separate pages with alternate content for search engines.

I'm curious how to go about fixing the url paths. When I enter the site from, say 'Video' it will load up the /video.php page and then any further link clicked will result in the following:

http://www.mywebsite.com/video.php#/aboutus    <- ugly

Q: Is there an easy way to make it drop the 'video.php' without affecting SEO?

Thanks!

Comment: How about getting /video.php to redirect to /#!/video/ if the user have Flash installed? That way you can serve the non-Flash content at /video.php and keep the urls nice and clean for your Flash app.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish that is to redirect it to a subdirectory instead of actual pages with anchored content. As for SEO and Flash, Yahoo and Bing can't read Flash well, if at all. Just make sure that you do NOT flatten the text layers in your Flash and you'll be golden. In short, creating an entire site in Flash is typically a bad idea from an SEO perspective.

If your site is already indexed and you're moving site structure around, be sure to login to Google Webmaster Tools and upload a new sitemap once everything is in place. If you don't even have one, go to www.auditmypc.com and have them create one for you for free.